# heroku application error for fastapi (python)

Tags: python, heroku, fastapi

I followed github/stackoverflow resources, watched youtube videos, read heroku official docs but in the end, I still getting error (network erro). Can someone help me what is the problem going on with my project?

I upoloaded project in github and linked with heroku. Used environment variable as heroku config vars with database strings, projects with project secret keys etc.

My **requirements.txt** file below

```
appdirs
typing
dnspython
email-validator
fastapi
motor
datetime
jose
passlib
dataclasses
typing-extensions
pydantic
starlette
uvicorn
bson
gunicorn
h11
click
pylint
astroid
websockets
```

In **Procfile** I wrote this in each different commits
`web: gunicorn -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker main:app`
and then this
`web: uvicorn main:app --host=0.0.0.0 --port=${PORT:-5000}`
and this
`web: uvicorn main:app --host="0.0.0.0" --port=${PORT:-8000}`
and also
`web: uvicorn main:app --host "0.0.0.0" --port ${PORT}`
but none of them are workable.
and also updated **runtime.txt** file several time with different python versions.

May be I tried every possibilities from internet but what is the god damn problem ?

Comment: Are you sure that your FastAPI app is located in top-level main.py file? Could you run your server locally with the same commands? Also check your logs in Heroku.

Comment: Yes, my app is running fine locally. And my app instance (__app = FastAPI()__) is located inside my main.py file

Comment: Check logs in Heroku. If something useful in there, please share

Comment: Can't see. it occurs:  ›   Error: Missing required flag:
 ›    -a, --app APP  app to run command against
 ›   See more help with --help

Comment: I can assume, that your dependencies are not installed correctly. Call pip freeze > requirements.txt. For some reason you don't have fixed versions in your requirements.txt.

Probably, your heroku app fetches older/newer versions, where --app flag is needed

Comment: As you said, I defined all the deps with versions and successfully installed everything although the problem remains same :/

Comment: Heroku has defined set of errors. What error do you get? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes

Comment: Also, please ensure that you generate your requirements.txt by calling "pip freeze > requirements.txt". You shouldn't write it by hand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236507/discussion-between-rishad-tanjim-and-alexandr-farkas).

Answer (score 0):

You must check the logs by running this command from your terminal.
"heroku logs --tail  -a [applicationname]".

In my case the issue is this "pip install "pymongo[srv]" which I found from the logs. In the solution is to add this  "dnspython==2.1.0" in the requirements.txt and redeploy.